# Google Analytics Via Node.js Proxy

Tags: node.js, express, google-analytics

I am trying to impliment a proxy for google analytics into my current site. I started by following [this guide](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/save-your-analytics-from-content-blockers-7ee08c6ec7ee).

After following all the steps I get a 400 error returned from google with no further information.

I downloaded google's analytics.js file and put it on my server, and replaced all instances of **www.google-analytics.com** with **"+location.host+"/analytics**. See the file here: https://pastebin.com/wimHim7x

I edited my tracking code from google to replace **'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'** with **'/analytics.js'**.

Here is the proxy info from my app.js file

```
function getIpFromReq (req) { // get the client's IP address
    var bareIP = ":" + ((req.connection.socket && req.connection.socket.remoteAddress)
        || req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.connection.remoteAddress || "");
    return (bareIP.match(/:([^:]+)$/) || [])[1] || "127.0.0.1";
}

// proxying requests from /analytics to www.google-analytics.com.
app.use("/analytics", proxy("www.google-analytics.com", {
    proxyReqPathResolver: function (req) {
        var path = req.url + (req.url.indexOf("?") === -1 ? "?" : "&")
            + "uip=" + encodeURIComponent(getIpFromReq(req));

        console.log(path)

        return path;
    }
}));
```

This is the page I get returned from google:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>400.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: Can you paste the results of that console.log here? It would help us see what you are hitting Google API with

Comment: `/analytics/collect?v=1&_v=j58&a=1584388288&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Flospec.com%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=LOSPEC&sd=24-bit&sr=1280x1024&vp=1263x564&je=0&fl=26.0%20r0&_u=AACAAEABI~&jid=&gjid=&cid=967273455.1498054647&tid=UA-100011684-1&_gid=2110618272.1503415569&z=1115098348`

Comment: I suppose that you don't use https in your request and that's why Google blocks your requests. Anyway, I think that you should respect users's desire to block unwanted analytics.